# Написал парсер на python, он собирает урлы и заголовки,как сделать так, чтоб он заходил на отдельные страницы(урлы уже в бд) и парсил их?

Tags: python, django, парсер, requests

Написал парсер, он собирает урлы и заголовки, они сохраняются в бд, как можно реализовать функционал, когда парсер может заходить на эти урлы и копировать данные оттуда в бд? Пробовал через циклы, но как-то не получается.

Comment: под словом "заходить на сайты"  - значит логинтися? под словом "собриет урлы" - значит определяет по regex URL в *.html? под словом "данные" - это сохранить весь обьем за URL  (сайт).пробовали Beautiful Soup?

Comment: логиниться не нужно. Собрал урлы со страниц,где размещены все посты сайта за месяц,теперь надо зайти на эти страницы с постами и распарсить их, и также дополнить бд. парсил все чeрез bs4 и requests

Comment: @kikillka_kirillov дайте знать что у вас под словом "бд" зарыто реальная  SQLlite/Postgress/MySQL... или просто список

Comment: под бд понимается sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**./requrce_url_extract.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_re = '(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?'

def get_url(page):
    '''Get URL page and return all found URLs as list'''
    url_ls = [ ]
    html = urlopen(page)
    bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    for link in bsobj.find_all('a', href=re.compile(url_re)):
        url_ls.append(link.get('href'))
    return(url_ls)

def lister(ls):
    for i in ls:
        print("\tURL {}".format(i))

def main():
    page = str(sys.argv[1])

    parent_urls = get_url(page)

    for p_url in parent_urls:
        print(p_url)
        lister(get_url(p_url))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Пример выхлопа:

```
$ ./requrce_url_extract.py  "http://gnu.org"  | head -n20
https://www.fsf.org/associate/support_freedom?referrer=4052
        URL https://www.fsf.org
        URL https://fsf.org/associate/benefits
        URL https://my.fsf.org/join/check
        URL https://my.fsf.org/associate/support_freedom/renew_fsf
        URL https://my.fsf.org/user?destination=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact%3Freset%3D1%26id%3D38
        URL https://www.gnu.org/thankgnus
        URL https://www.fsf.org/about/free-software-foundation-privacy-policy
        URL https://civicrm.org/
        URL https://www.fsf.org/about/free-software-foundation-privacy-policy
        URL http://agpl.fsf.org/crm.fsf.org/CURRENT/
        URL https://weblabels.fsf.org/crm.fsf.org/CURRENT/
https://www.pureos.net/
        URL http://repo.pureos.net/pureos/pool/main/
        URL https://tracker.pureos.net/
        URL https://twitter.com/puri_sm
        URL https://mastodon.social/@purism
        URL https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
        URL https://puri.sm/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = []

#в urls передайте все урлы в виде строк чтоб полчуился такой список:
#urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3...']

for url in urls:
    html = urlopen(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    parse_page(bs)
    #я не знаю какие данные со страниц вам нужны, поэтому  код функции parse_page пишите сами
```